# Test if a package (or package option) is loaded

Tags: conditionals, babel, incompatibility, package-writing, french

`[french]{babel}` (aka `frenchb`) is incompatible with some other packages, such as `tikz`, since it tries to insert `\thinspace` before semi-colons.

In order to make these two play nice, you have to call `\shorthandoff{;}` in the document.

Now I have a package that uses `tikz` and I would like to locally disable the semi-colon for `babel`, instead of disabling it for the whole document. I could hack the `.sty` of the package to do that, knowing that I'm using `frenchb`, but I would rather make something clean and portable.

Is there a way in my package that I can test if `frenchb` is loaded and disable semi-colon management with `babel` locally, so the package doesn't have to be hacked?

**Edit:**

Martin's solution gives me something like this in general:

```
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\@babel@loaded}{0}
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{babel}                                                 
  {\renewcommand{\@babel@loaded}{1}}                                                      
  {\renewcommand{\@babel@loaded}{0}}                                                      
}
\newcommand{\somecommandusingsemicolon}{
  \ifthenelse{\@babel@loaded=1}{\shorthandoff{;}}{}  
  % code with semi-colon here
}
```

and in the specific case of tikz:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{babel}
  {%
    \g@addto@macro\tikz@installcommands{%
      \shorthandoff{;}%
    }
    \g@addto@macro\tikz@uninstallcommands{%
      \shorthandon{;}%
    }
  }
  {\relax}
}
```

Comment: Related (just for classes instead for packages): [Which documentclass is being used?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73/2975).

Comment: Instead of `\ifthenelse{\@babel@loaded=1}{\shorthandoff{;}}{}` just define a macro which is normally empty or `\relax` but defined to `\shorthandoff{;}` when `babel` is loaded. See also my `tikz` specific solution.

Comment: @Martin: Great, I updated my edit to reflect that.

Comment: make sure to mind unwanted spaces, i.e. add `%` at the end of the line if required. Also `{\relax}` doesn't really make sense, `{}` is just fine.

Comment: There's also `\ltx@ifpackageloaded`, refer to [conditionals - How to implement a command that checks for loaded packages? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35282/how-to-implement-a-command-that-checks-for-loaded-packages) for details.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use the internal LaTeX macro `\@ifpackageloaded` to test if a package was loaded:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{<name>}{<true>}{<false>}
```

There are also:

```
\@ifpackagewith{<name>}{<option-list>}{<true>}{<false>}
\@ifpackagelater{<name>}{<date YYYY/MM/DD>}{<true>}{<false>}
```

For further macro see the document linked in [Documentation reference for LaTeX internal commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/documentation-reference-for-latex-internal-commands/10465#10465).

---

In the case of `tikz` it would be best to add your code to the macros `\tikz@installcommands` and `\tikz@uninstallcommands`. The first is executed at the begin of a `tikzpicture` and enables all the `tikz` commands only defined there and the latter is executed at the begin of node content and changes the definitions back to there normal state. This way you can have French text inside the nodes.

You can add code to the macros using:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{babel}{%
    \g@addto@macro\tikz@installcommands{%
      \shorthandoff{;}%
    }%
    \g@addto@macro\tikz@uninstallcommands{%
      \shorthandon{;}%
    }%
}{}
```

I'm just guessing here that `\shorthandon` is the opposite of `\shorthandoff`.

Comment: @Martin: `\@ifclassloaded` seems to be only usable in preamble. Is that right?

Comment: @Raphink: Yes, they are marked as `\@onlypreamble`. You would need to test for the package in question at the end of the preamble, e.g. using `\AtBeginDocument{...}`, and set a global flag for your document macros.

Comment: @Martin: Right. I would like to disable semi-colon management very locally, in a given macro. If I do a `\AtBeginDocument`, it will still affect the whole scope.

Comment: @Raphink: Right, that's why I wrote "set a global flag for your document macros" not "change your settings". You then use that flag locally.

Comment: @Martin: I edited the question to make an example with your proposal. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

In newer LaTeX versions, `\@ifpackageloaded` can also be `\IfPackageLoadedTF`.

[image: source2e.pdf extract]

Usage is identical.

---

Another option is `\ltx@ifpackageloaded` from `ltxcmds` package (the main advantage of `ltxcmds` package is it being usable from plain TeX, but there isn't really a standardized mechanism to load a package in plain TeX apart from `\input` which doesn't really keep track of this):

[image: ltxcmds package documentation]