# How to implement a command that checks for multiple loaded packages?

Tags: packages, conditionals, programming

I use the following code to check if a package is loaded:

```
\RequirePackage{ltxcmds}
\newcommand{\IfPackageLoaded}[2]{\ltx@ifpackageloaded{#1}{#2}{}}
```

However, sometimes I want to check if more than one package is loaded. Therefore I would like to generalise the command, such that more than one package can be added in a list separated with commas:

```
\IfPackagesLoaded{xcolor, colortbl, hyperref}{
...
}%
```

What would the typical implementation of the processing of such a list look like?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the LaTeX kernel's `\@for` macro, which processes a comma-separated list, in conjunction with an `if` switch. The `\IfPackagesLoaded` macro initially sets the switch to true, then goes through the list and sets the switch to false if a package is missing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ltxcmds}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{doc}

\makeatletter
\newif\ifallloaded
\newcommand{\IfPackagesLoaded}[3]{%
  \allloadedtrue
  \@for\@tempa:=#1\do{%
    \ltx@ifpackageloaded{\@tempa}{}{\allloadedfalse}}%
  \ifallloaded #2\else #3\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\IfPackagesLoaded{fixltx2e,doc}{yes}{no}
\IfPackagesLoaded{hyperref,fixltx2e}{yes}{no}

\end{document}
```

Comment: how robust is this for list for the occurrence of spaces before or after commas and a comma at the beginning or end of the list?

Comment: Note that `\@ifpackageloaded` only works in the preamble, while `\ltx@ifpackageloaded` also works in the document body.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: Spaces are taken as part of an element. Preceding or trailing commas create empty elements. So, not robust in this sense. The list should be a normal comma-separated list.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Not with the `pkgindoc` package :-P

Comment: @AndreyVihrov: Well, just check if `\ver@<package>.sty` exits yourself. Easy enough.

Comment: I want to use `\ltx@ifpackageloaded`. Would checking for `\ver@<package>.sty` have any advantage`? And pkgindoc does too much. 
@AndreyVihrov: How could i make it robust?

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: `\ltx@ifpackageloaded` does check if `\ver@<package>.sty` is defined. My point is that is an easy enough code to do it yourself, instead of loaded a not too small packages for it.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: Very well, I performed the substitution. Why do you need to account for such cases?

Comment: In my template I sometimes require such checks to add bugfixing code

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech: I suggest you accept egreg's answer, because it's a more enhanced version of this answer.

Answer (score 9):

As Andrey stated you can use the LaTeX internal macro `\@for` to go through a comma separated list. Another useful macro is `\zap@space`, which is normally used to remove spaces from a package option list.

I would define a `\next` macro which is usually *true*, i.e. expands to the first of the next two arguments but is that to expand to the second instead if any not-loaded package is encountered. I then redefine an internal macro (inside a group) to skip all other packages.
The package-loaded-test done by `\lxt@ifpackageloaded` (`ltxcmds` package) and `\@ifpackageloaded` (LaTeX core, but only-in-preamble) is to check if the macro `\ver@<package>.sty` is define, which holds the version of the package (but can be empty). I added this code here directly to not be dependent to a package just for this small code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{doc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfPackagesLoaded}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \let\next\@firstoftwo
    \@for\@tempa:=#1\do{%
        \expandafter\@IfPackagesLoaded\expandafter{\@tempa}%
    }%
    \expandafter\endgroup
    \next
}
\def\@IfPackagesLoaded#1{%
    \edef\@tempa{\zap@space#1 \@empty}% remove any spaces
    \expandafter\ifx\csname ver@\@tempa.sty\endcsname\relax% package not loaded?
        \let\next\@secondoftwo
        \let\@IfPackagesLoaded\@gobble% No need for further checks
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\IfPackagesLoaded{fixltx2e,doc}{\typeout{yes}}{\typeout{no}}
\IfPackagesLoaded{ fixltx2e , doc }{\typeout{yes}}{\typeout{no}}
\IfPackagesLoaded{hyperref,fixltx2e}{\typeout{yes}}{\typeout{no}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: can you comment, in the best case line after line, what this code does? I understand that the for does an iteration, and in each \@IfPackageLoaded is called with \@tempa. But what is the meaning of next, what do you do with `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo` and why can you rename `\@IfPackagesLoaded` within the command itself? I would assume that it is not available in the second iteration in that case. So basically I do not understand most of this code...

Answer (score 7):

As others have remarked, the kernel provides `\@ifpackageloaded` and **[`ltxcmds`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxcmds)** also `\ltx@ifpackageloaded` that can be used in the document.

```
\usepackage{ltxcmds,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfPackagesLoaded}[1]{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \def\do##1{\edef\@tempa{\zap@space##1 \@empty}%
    \ltx@ifpackageloaded{\@tempa}{}{\@tempswafalse}}%
  \docsvlist{#1}%
  \if@tempswa\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}
\makeatother
```

Processing the list element through `\zap@space` ensures that no spaces around the package name remain also if the call is

```
\IfPackagesLoaded{ abc , xyz }
```

The conditional `\if@tempswa` is predefined by LaTeX and is used as a "scratch conditional"; it should be relied on only on immediate application, as other macros might change its truth value. The idea is that the conditional is set to true at the beginning and each "not already loaded" package in the list sets it to false. Therefore it will be still true at the end only if all packages in the list are already loaded.

The final line uses this fact and uses the code in the second or third arguments to `\IfPackagesLoaded`. Actually they aren't really arguments to `\IfPackagesLoaded`, but from the user's point of view it makes no difference. I might have defined `\IfPackagesLoaded` with three arguments by using as the last instruction

```
\if@tempswa#2\else#3\fi
```

but the way chosen is better as it leaves no trailing `\else` or `\fi` when the code in the second and third argument is executed.

Comment: As I understand \docsvlist processed for each index in the csv list the \do command. But what are these predefined if sequences `\@tempswatrue` and what does the last line with `\if@tempswa`

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech See edited message with explanations; you can use the idea of `\zap@space` also in Andrey's code, by putting `\edef\@tempa{\xp\xp\xp\zap@space\xp\@tempa\space\@empty}` just after the opening brace following `\do`; here `\xp` stands for `\expandafter`.

Comment: Actually I would have expected that there are 2 or three arguments such that there is an if and an else branch. You say that you get around this by using  \if@tempswa\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi` but now I completely fail to understand how many argument the command has?

Comment: The command has one argument, but the call must be `\IfPackagesLoaded{list}{true}{false}`; actually `{true}` and `{false}` will be absorbed as arguments either by `\@firstoftwo` or `\@secondoftwo`, depending on the test. It's very common in LaTeX; for example `\section` is defined as having *no* argument as you can easily check doing `\show\section`. It's not relevant for the user, though, who can think to `\section` as taking an optional and a mandatory argument. You can see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21262) for a discussion about `\@firstoftwo` and `\@secondoftwo`.