# Check if multiple column types are defined fails

Tags: conditionals, programming, columns

Using the commands of the discussion [How to check if a column type is defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35527/how-to-check-if-a-column-type-is-defined) and [How to implement a command that checks for loaded packages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35282/how-to-implement-a-command-that-checks-for-loaded-packages)

I have build an enviroment to check if more than one column is defined

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\CheckIfColumntypeDefined[1]{%
  \providebool{tpl@coltype@#1}
  \ifcsdef{NC@find@\string#1}%
    {\setbool{tpl@coltype@#1}{true}}%
    {\ifcsdef{columntype@\string#1}
      {\setbool{tpl@coltype@#1}{true}}%
      {\setbool{tpl@coltype@#1}{false}}%
    }%
}

\newcommand\IfColumntypeDefined[3]{%
  \CheckIfColumntypeDefined{#1}
  \ifboolexpr{ bool{tpl@coltype@#1} }{#2}{#3}%
}

\newcommand{\IfColumntypesDefined}[1]{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \def\do##1{%
    % define \@tempa with trimmed index element.
    \edef\@tempa{\zap@space##1 \@empty}%
    % check if package of current index is loaded
    \IfColumntypeDefined{\@tempa}{}{\@tempswafalse}%
  }%
  % Process csv list with command \do (etoolbox)
  \docsvlist{#1}%
  % ??
  \if@tempswa\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\IfColumntypeDefined{L}{L is defined}{L is not defined}
\IfColumntypeDefined{C}{C is defined}{C is not defined}

\IfColumntypesDefined{L,C}
{L and C columns are defined}
{L and C columns are not defined}

\end{document}
```

It however returns always false which I do not understand and do not know how to debug. So the output is

> L is deﬁned   C is deﬁned
>
> L and C columns are not deﬁned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any point in defining `\IfColumntypesDefined` with a list of column types; however the problem is in the

```
\IfColumntypeDefined{\@tempa}{}{\@tempswafalse}
```

line. With

```
\expandafter\IfColumntypeDefined\expandafter{\@tempa}{}{\@tempswafalse}
```

you get the correct result. The reason is that `\string#1` is used in `\CheckIfColumntypeDefined` (which is a good thing, because it protects against wrong input).