# how do I check that french-babel is loaded?

Tags: packages, programming

(1) What argument `<arg>` do I supply to `\ltx@ifpackageloaded{<arg>}` to specifically catch french babel?
(2) Would you mind compiling the MWE with `\usepackage{siunitx}` commented out. If it produces compiler error `! Undefined control sequence.<argument> \text{loaded} ...eLoaded[babel]+: \myIsPackageLoaded[babel]` as it does for me, I would like to know why?!

```
\documentclass{minimal}
%RN. 10Aug16. MWE_17_04
\usepackage{ltxcmds}
\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}
%\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{MyUtilities}
\begin{document}
\verb+\myIsPackageLoaded[babel]+: \myIsPackageLoaded[babel]

\verb+\myIsPackageLoaded[frenchb]+: \myIsPackageLoaded[frenchb]

\verb+\myIsPackageLoaded[french-babel]+: \myIsPackageLoaded[french-babel]     
\end{document}

\ProvidesPackage{MyUtilities}
%\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\myIsPackageLoaded{O{}}{\myIsPackageLoaded_Main:nn {#1}} 
\cs_new:Npn \myIsPackageLoaded_Main:nn #1
  {
    \ltx@ifpackageloaded{#1}{\text{loaded}}{\text{not~loaded}}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: Are you missing a `\makeatletter...\makeatother` pair needed for `\ltx@ifpackageloaded`?

Comment: A post Ryan Reich July 8/12 states that `\makeatletter ...\makeatother` is not required in `.sty` files.

Comment: asfaf `\ltx@ifpackageloaded{<name of package>}{<code for true>}{<code for false>}'

Comment: The answer is not trivial. For the reasons explained in the `babel` docs, language names may refer to different things. Checking if `frenchb` is used as an option is not the right answer, because you can load the `french` language with `french` or `francais`, too. A better test is if `l<@lang>` and `\date<lang>` exist.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth: True, I didn't notice the `\ProvidesPackage` command -- which is difficult to see, since example code and `.sty` are merged in your post

Comment: Daniel Flipo, maintainer of the `A Babel language definition file for French` has supplied me with following 2-liner which solves my problem perfectly and without fuss:  `\ifdefined\frenchbsetup
\shorthandoff{;} % \shorthandon{;}
\fi`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I am struggling with the editing features of TeX-Exchange and would be happy to adopt your advise on how, in future, to separate `.tex` and `.sty` components.

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth: Just write some line in real text, without indentation between the code parts, e.g. `... and here is the package code`

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX has built-in support for this. See for example this post of which is what you're looking for: [Test if a package (or package option) is loaded](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16199/test-if-a-package-or-package-option-is-loaded)

Comment: I had read the posts. The solution there detects if `babel` is loaded, for any language. What I would need is the ability to detect if french-babel is loaded, in other words: what value for `<language>` do I have to plug into `\ltx@ifpackageloaded{<language>}...` for TRUE to be returned if and only if french-babel had been loaded.

Comment: It is mentioned in the approved answer: \@ifpackagewith{babel}{frenchb}{...}{...}

Comment: ahhhh, missed that!

Comment: But see my comment above.