# Can my document class require a package to be available without actually loading it?

Tags: packages, document-classes

When you `\RequirePackage{foo}` in a document class, this "loads" the package so you can start using it. But what if you don't want to do that? What if you only want to ensure it is available for loading, e.g. for other code to be able to `\usepackage{foo}` later on?

Is that possible?

Motivation: I'm going to be [deferring the loading of a package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392175/) within a document class, but I do want to fail immediately if the package isn't there so as not to confuse whoever is reading the logs.

Comment: Use `\IfFileExists`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98203/can-i-test-if-a-file-exists

Comment: @egreg: And the file must be `foo.sty` and nothing else?

Comment: `\IfFileExists{foo.sty}{Do something if it exists}{Do something else otherwise}`

Comment: Does `\IfFileExists` look in all of the places that `\usepackage` would?

Comment: What is the use-case for this? It seems pointless. Either the package will get loaded later or it isn't needed. Why does the class need to poke its nose into the business at all? A class is responsible for what it needs. It shouldn't go second-guessing what some *other* code might need, if we ever get there.

Comment: Why would it confuse the person reading the logs? This is a completely standard thing to do. If you want to make clear that your package is responsible for the load, use `\IfFileExist{\Require...}{error...}` in the deferred code.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer: Yes.  As a matter of fact, `\usepackage` itself indirectly calls `\IfFileExists` to load the `.sty` file.

Comment: @GuM - thanks. I was under the impression that it only checked a single file name or path.

Comment: @koleygr: I agree.