# Class memoir Error: Font command \it is not supported

Tags: fonts, memoir, ieeeconf

I have this line in a file which I use at the same time for my phd thesis and for a paper.

```
\setlist*[enumerate,1]{label=\it{\arabic*)}}
```

For the paper which is

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10 pt, conference]{ieeeconf}  % Comment this line out
```

it does not give me any error.

But for the thesis which is something like:

```
\documentclass[english,11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{memoir}
```

It gives me the error:

```
! Class memoir Error: Font command \it is not supported.
See the memoir class documentation for explanation.
```

I understand that the class memoir does not allow the use of old commands like `\it` but how can I have the file still existing and tell it:

`if a memoir is calling you then do not take this line into account`

`else take it into account`

Something like that.

Thanks for the precious help.

Comment: use `\itshape` instead of `\it`: `label=\itshape\arabic*)`

Comment: Have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16199/test-if-a-package-or-package-option-is-loaded then you can use `\gdef\it#1{#1}` for the true fork, when memoir is loaded.

Comment: `\it` never took an argument so `\it{\arabic*}` looks wrong anyway, the argument form is `\textit{\arabic*}` and that is defined in the latex format so will work here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Plain-TeX font-switching commands -- `\rm`, `\sf`, `\tt`, `\bf`, `\it`, `\sc` and `\sl` -- are not defined in the LaTeX kernel, and they are considered badly deprecated in LaTeX documents. One should use `\rmfamily`, `\sffamily`, `\ttfamily`, `\bfseries`, `\itshape`, `\scshape`, and `\slshape` instead.

Some, but definitely not all, LaTeX document classes do define the Plain-TeX font-switching commands. As you've noticed and report correctly, `ieeeconf` is such a document class. In contrast, `memoir` does not define these commands -- *unless* you provide the document class option `oldfontcommands`:

```
\documentclass[english, 11pt, a4paper, twoside, openright, oldfontcommands]{memoir}
```

Even then, `memoir` will issue warning messages whenever one of the deprecated commands is encountered.

Incidentally, neither `\it` nor `\itshape` take an argument -- they are switches. Hence, it's not entirely correct (syntactically speaking) to write

```
\setlist*[enumerate,1]{label=\it{\arabic*)}}
```

Instead, do get used to writing

```
\setlist*[enumerate,1]{label={\itshape\arabic*)}}
```

This'll work "out of the box" with all document classes, not just `ieeeconf`.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `oldfontcommands` class option:

```
\documentclass[...,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
```

Comment: @Mico Your answer was much more generic than mine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think that @Mico's is more detailed and clear

Comment: Thx for the answer, you've just helped me so much!