# Custom class (*.sty) with different document class (e.g. beamer)

Tags: latex-base

I am writing my own class/preamble for LaTeX and need to differ inside if a package is required and therefore loaded based on the document class.

Example:
I want to load `\RequirePackage{hyperref}` for all document classes but beamer, because it's pre loaded from beamer.

Is this somehow possible?

Thank you.

Comment: `\RequirePackage{hyperref}` does not make any harm if the `hyperref` package is already loaded, therefore you can load it unconditionally.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use `\@ifpackageloaded{<name>}{<true>}{<false>}` in the `.sty` file to test if a package has already been loaded. See also [Test if a package (or package option) is loaded](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16200/110998). But as @PM noted, `\RequirePackage` loads the package only if it hasn't been loaded yet, and otherwise does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help. I've read through and I got a solution. Here is an example with beamer and geometry:

```latex
\@ifclassloaded{beamer}%
  {
  }%True
  {  \RequirePackage[a4paper]{geometry}
  }%False
\makeatother%
```

Maybe this will help somebody

Comment: One advice: you should get accustomed to always remove whitespaces after `{` and `}` or put `%` sign immediately after those brackets if a line break follows in your sty and tex sources. Otherwise you might end up with horizontal skips in the output DVI or PDF, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX StackExchange.

You mentioned you wanted to write your own class with `.sty` extension, these kinds of files are called `packages` not `classes`. I assume you want to create a template to ease and standardize the process of creating documents for the future. If this is your goal, you should create a `class`, which has `.cls` extension.

Must-read before writing any kind of class or package is already installed on your system if LaTeX is properly installed. Just go to your terminal and type the following command

```
$ texdoc clsguide
```

or simply [click here](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/clsguide.pdf) for the same content. I highly recommend getting familiar with `texdoc` command. Also, [The LaTeX Companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201362996) and [LaTeX: A Document Preparation System](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201529831) are two great resources.

After reading the clsguide, I you will grasp more about your problem and how things work for `class` and `packages`. If not, you will be able to express it more explicitly.

Have fun.