# xcolor - print only if (not) monochrome?

Tags: color, conditionals

When I use the `xcolor` package, I can pass the option `monochrome`, which turns all colors into black. Is it possible to define commands `\mono` and `\notmono` that will print their content only if the option monochrome is/isn't given?

Say,

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[
% monochrome
]{xcolor}    
\newcommand{\notmono}[1]{???} % No idea how to define this
\newcommand{\mono}[1]{???} % No idea how to define this

\begin{document}

\mono{Print this only if option monochrome IS given to xcolor.}
\notmono{Print this only if option monochrome is NOT given to xcolor.}    

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: I could define

```
\newcommand{\mono}[1]{}
\newcommand{\notmono}[1]{#1}
```

in case I do not give the `monochrome` option, and redefine them when necessary to

```
\newcommand{\mono}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\notmono}[1]{}
```

But I'd still like to know if there is a better way of doing that.

Comment: Special case of [conditionals - Test if a package (or package option) is loaded - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16199/test-if-a-package-or-package-option-is-loaded/16200#16200) (search for `@ifpackagewith`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `xcolor`'s code, there is a `\newif` command `\ifcolors@` that is true by default and set to false when the `monochrome` option is used. So you could define your commands `\notmono` and `\mono` to check `\ifcolors@`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[
% monochrome
]{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\notmono}[1]{\ifcolors@#1\else\fi}
\newcommand{\mono}[1]{\ifcolors@\else#1\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mono{Print this only if option monochrome IS given to xcolor.}
\notmono{Print this only if option monochrome is NOT given to xcolor.}    

\end{document}
```

The above example outputs

[image]

Uncommenting the `monochrome` option, it rather outputs

[image]

as expected.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! I accepted your answer; thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid problems with `\if..`-`\else`-`\fi`-nesting in case the argument of `\mono`/`\notmono` contains unbalanced `\if..`-`\else`-`\fi`-expressions you can fork between gobbling/delivering the argument:

```latex
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[%
%monochrome
]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\mono}{\ifcolors@\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi}
\newcommand*{\notmono}{\ifcolors@\expandafter\@firstofone\else\expandafter\@gobble\fi}
%\newcommand*{\notmono}{\expandafter\unless\mono}
\newcommand*\CheckWhetherMono{\ifcolors@\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mono{Print this only if option monochrome IS given to xcolor.}
\notmono{Print this only if option monochrome is NOT given to xcolor.}

\CheckWhetherMono{Print this only if option monochrome IS given to xcolor.}%
                 {Print this only if option monochrome is NOT given to xcolor.}


Now the weird things that malevolent users might do:

\iftrue
\mono{\fi Print this only if option monochrome IS given to xcolor.}
\notmono{\fi Print this only if option monochrome is NOT given to xcolor.}

\iftrue
\CheckWhetherMono{\fi Print this only if option monochrome IS given to xcolor.}%
                 {\fi Print this only if option monochrome is NOT given to xcolor.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice! Preemptively fixed a bug. Thanks @Ulrich