# How to configure theorems depending on the document class?

Tags: numbering, conditionals, theorems, document-classes

I would like to have  `\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]` if the `book` class is loaded but  `\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[section]` if the `article` class is loaded.  Can I do this with some sort of conditional?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{theorem}
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter] %if book
\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[section] %if article

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this question [Which document class is being used?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73/2693) should answer your question.

Comment: For others that can't work out solutions here: I had a similar need but the place where knowledge of class was needed was inside a style file (`.sty`). Solutions here had LaTeX fail. It worked using `\@ifclassloaded` along with bits taken from: [conditionals - Test if a package (or package option) is loaded - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16199/test-if-a-package-or-package-option-is-loaded)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Altough, the link Alan points to has the required info, that page assumes that you already know about `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother` macros, which depending on the experience level one may not have encountered.

The following is intended to exit if a class other than `book` or `article` is used.  You can remove the `\QUITHERE` macro if that is not desired.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{theorem}

\makeatletter%
\@ifclassloaded{book}{%
    \newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]%if book
    \typeout{Using book class.}%
}{%
    \@ifclassloaded{article}{%
        \newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[section]%if article
        \typeout{Using article class.}%
    }{%
        \typeout{Error: Unsupported class: only 'article' and 'book' are suported.}\QUITHERE
    }%
}%
\makeatother%

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Also see similar question on [how to configure fancyhdr depending on the document class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25489/how-to-configure-fancyhdr-depending-on-the-document-class)

Answer (score 5):

It seems your aim is to make theorem numbers subordinate to the highest (non-`\part`) sectioning level defined in the respective document class -- `\chapter` for the `book` class, and `\section` for `article`. Therefore, I suggest to test not for the name of the loaded class, but for the availability of the `\chapter` command. If this command is undefined (or its meaning is `\relax`), number theorems per section, else, per chapter. This method will also work for, e.g., the `report` class and the `KOMA-Script` classes.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\ifundef{\chapter}{%
  \newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[section]% if \chapter not defined
  \typeout{Numbering theorems per section.}%
}{%
  \newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]% if \chapter defined
  \typeout{Numbering theorems per chapter.}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{teo}
A theorem.
\end{teo}

\end{document}
```