# How to configure fancyhdr depending on the document class

Tags: conditionals, document-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure theorems depending on the document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25370/how-to-configure-theorems-depending-on-the-document-class)

I would like to have if the book class is loaded but
if the article class is loaded. Can I do this with some sort of
conditional?

I tried, but failed.

```
\makeatletter%
\@ifclassloaded{book}{%
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
  \fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
  \fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
  \fancyfoot[LO,RE]{Régis}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  }
  \typeout{Using book class.}%
}{%
\@ifclassloaded{article}{%
%   \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
  \fancyhead{}
%   \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
  \fancyhead[R]{\bfseries\rightmark}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\bfseries\thepage}
  \fancyfoot[L]{Régis}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  }
  \typeout{Using article class.}%
}{%
\@ifclassloaded{report}{%
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
  \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}
  \fancyhead[L]{\bfseries\leftmark}
  \fancyhead[R]{\bfseries\rightmark}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\bfseries\thepage}
  \fancyfoot[L]{Régis}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
  \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  }
  \typeout{Using report class.}%
}{%
  \typeout{Error: Unsupported class: 'article' or 'report' or 'book' are suported.}\QUITHERE
}%
}%
\makeatother%
```

Comment: Didn't we just answer an identical question of yours like this: [How to configure theorems depending on the documentclass?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25370/2693)  This is (another) duplicate of [Which document class is being used?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73/2693)

Comment: Alan is correct. Just inserting the appropriate sections of your code into the solution at [How to configure theorems depending on documentclass](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25370/how-to-configure-theorems-depending-on-the-document-class) should work.

Comment: I tried, but failed.

Comment: can not you have two environments `\makeatletter%` on the same file?

Comment: The `#1` is intended to refer to the first parameter to a macro call.  Here you are not defining a macro so it doesn't have meaning.

Comment: There should not be any problems with multiple uses of `\makeatletter ... \makeatother`. I don't think you can nest then but have not tried that.

Comment: @Regis Two problems: (i) You are missing a brace in the line `\typeout{Using article class} (needs one more closing brace) (ii) the macro `\QUITHERE` is not a real macro: it was a pseudo-code macro that Peter used in his answer, so remove it.

Comment: @Regis Ideally what you're trying to do should be done by passing options to a package, not by having a huge preamble like this.  You should read the documentation for writing classes `texdoc clsguide` for some information on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started. Just add the appropriate settings to `BookHeader`, `ArticleHead`, and `ReportHead`.  Within these three you can use `#1` to refer to what was passed to `\SetHeaders`.

The following is intended to exit if a class other than book or article or report is used. You can remove the \QUITHERE macro if that is not desired.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\BookHeader}[1]{% Add any customizations for book class here.
  \typeout{Using book class.}%
}%

\newcommand*{\ArticleHead}[1]{% Add any customizations for article class here.
  \typeout{Using article class.}%
}%

\newcommand*{\ReportHead}[1]{% Add any customizations for report class here.
  \typeout{Using report class.}%
}%

\makeatletter%
\newcommand*{\SetHeaders}[1]{%
    \@ifclassloaded{book}{\BookHeader{#1}%
    }{\@ifclassloaded{article}{\ArticleHead{#1}%
    }{\@ifclassloaded{report}{\ReportHead{#1}}{%
      \typeout{Error: Unsupported class: 'article' or 'report' or 'book' are suported.}\QUITHERE
    }}}%
}%
\makeatother%

\SetHeaders{foo}%


\begin{document}
Testing...
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is definitely easier to read code.  (The original code also worked; see my comment above.)  Also, @Regis Peter has the pseudo-code macro `\QUITHERE`; this document will fail inelegantly if an unsupported document class is used.

Comment: How to use `\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter.\ #1}{}}` for appear 1.foo (name of chapter) without CHAPTER 1.foo. Is failed in Report.

Comment: @Alan: Thanks, have added the comment about \QUITHERE. I find it very useful to exit for cases that I have not yet handled in the code.

Comment: It's also possible to use `\PackageError{<package name>}{<error text>}{<help text>}` inside a document.