# If-then in a document style for specific document classes

Tags: memoir, conditionals, document-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which documentclass is being used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73/which-documentclass-is-being-used)

I want to make a style that would include some specific instructions if the document is using the `memoir` class, but I don't want those instructions to be included if the document is using another class. I've found some information about if-then statements in LaTeX, but not how to test the document class.

Comment: * [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Have a look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73/which-documentclass-is-being-used

Comment: If the question whlt3 pointed you to solves your problem, please let us now. In this case, we'd probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. Also, note that we don't usually put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: That post did solve my problem, and the advice on using SX will probably solver future problems :)