# How to check for document class in conditionals

Tags: packages, conditionals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which documentclass is being used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73/which-documentclass-is-being-used)

I know how to use conditionals in LaTeX, but I need to check what documentclass is being used.

I need to not include a package when I'm using `g-brief` or `g-brief2`, so how can check for that?

I tried:

```
\@ifclassloaded{g-brief}{%
}{%
\@ifclassloaded{g-brief2}{%
}{%
    \usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
}}
```

But I get the following error:

```
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
\@->\spacefactor 
                 \@m {}
l.29 \@
       ifclassloaded{g-brief}{%
```

I'm using XeLaTeX.

Comment: This is a clear dupe: I'm closing.

Comment: Well, at least a link to the original would be nice, I really don't know how to do that!

Comment: @polemon There's a link to the duplicate, added at the top of the question. Closing is just to keep the site content clean, sorted and accessible, nothing personal. Also, if you change the question so that it becomes different, it can be reopened.

Comment: All macros with an `@` in their names, must be put between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, except when they are inside a package or class file.

Comment: On `@` as a 'letter', see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do