# conditional commands in .sty file, conditional on \documentclass

Tags: conditionals, document-classes, package-writing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which document class is being used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73/which-document-class-is-being-used)

I'd like to include conditional formatting in a .sty file, conditional on the document class of the document that invokes it.

For example, I'd like to redefine the `\section` command like this for all `article`, `letter`, and `book` document classes, but have no special formatting for documents making use of the `beamer` class.

```
\renewcommand*\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                               {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                               {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                               {\normalfont\Large}}
```

I'd appreciate any help on how to do this.

Comment: @lockstep you are true and my answer below provides moreorless the exact copy of the macro `\@ifclassloaded`

Comment: Consider writing custom document classes based off of article, book, letter, and putting the section-formatting commands in each class instead. I normally put specific formatting into a class file instead of a generic style file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** the same macro as I provide below is a part of LaTeX core. It is called `\@ifclassloaded` and has the exactly same usage as my `\IfClass` below, which is therefore useless.

```
\documentclass{article}

% THIS IS THE CODE YOU NEED
\makeatletter
\def\IfClass#1#2#3{\@ifundefined{opt@#1.cls}{#3}{#2}}
\makeatother
% END OF THE CODE

\begin{document}

\IfClass{article}{ARTICLE YES}{ARTICLE NO}

\IfClass{report}{REPORT YES}{REPORT NO}

\end{document}
```