# conditional usepackage given documentclass

Tags: conditionals, document-classes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which document class is being used?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73/which-document-class-is-being-used)

How would I conditionally `usepackage{enumitem}` if the document class is memoir (but not beamer)?

Could I use the etoolbox primitives, or do I have to define something using renewcommand?

My setup is that I have two documents — `memoir` document, and a `beamer` document — both including the same latex document, which does most of the includes.

Comment: @PeterGrill: I've edited the question.

Comment: Ah, thanks!  Sorry, I did some searching, but didn't find this!

Comment: Thats ok. If you couldn't easily find it most likely others won't either, so having dupes helps to locate things.