# Conditional for documentclass

Tags: conditionals, document-classes

I was wondering whether it is possible to execute a command depending on the used documentclass.

```
\documentclass{dinbrief}
%\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}
\ifthenelse{<documentclass is dinbrief>}{\setlength{\headheight}{20mm}}{}
\the\headheight
\end{document}
```

I think in principle this code should work. But what exactly should go in the conditional of the ifthenelse (instead of ). Via google I could not find out if there is a variable holding the documentclass so can it be requested during compilation, and if it exists, what's its name?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73/which-document-class-is-being-used/97

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Are the options ``[11pt, a4paper]`` relevant to your question? If not, please don't include such details. You can have a look at the [guide for how to minimalize your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/9077).

Comment: Thats right. corrected.