# Ignore \pause macro from beamer in scrartcl document

Tags: beamer

I'm bulding up a beamer presentation and an article.
Therefore I have to create some figures which are used in both files.
So I created an additional .tex file for each figure which I include in every file.
This results in errors, because the `\pause` command shouldnt be used in `scrartcl`.
Is there a solution to ignore these errors or to suppres the `\pause` command in the `scrarctl` environment?

If MWE is needed, I'll add one. But I think it's a general problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73/which-document-class-is-being-used

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for me. But I got the idea to use `\newcommand{\pause}{ }` inside the preamble so that it replaces all `\pause` by an empty space. 
But thanks, your Link brought me there!

Comment: "Related"... you could patch the command the conditionally use \pause if `beamer` is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it my own:
Simply ad `\newcommand{\pause}{ }`inside the preamble to replace all occurences of `\pause` by a whitespace in the documenet.

Comment: `\providecommand{\pause}{}` would be even more portable for the code. It would work with an existing `\pause` (e.g `beamer` class) too.

Comment: You might notice some extra space when doing this. You could look into using \@bsphack and \@esphack to fix this if its a problem. It might be fine though in a figure.

Comment: To avoid spacing problems, I'd simply use `\let\pause\relax`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Not as convenient as `\provide...`, though...?

Comment: @cfr In what sense?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Just the reason Christian mentioned: you can put it wherever and not worry about making sure that Beamer doesn't see it. Whether this is an issue or not depends on your workflow and how things are split between files. That's all I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You could load `beamerarticle`. Then you can use whatever commands and environments you like from Beamer. For example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {Slide 1};
    \pause
    \node [below] {Slide 2};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'm not going to post the output because it is completely and utterly uninteresting.